# NodeJS beginner : Fetching data from other URL using Requestify

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a newbie in NodeJs and i have to shift my code igniter server api's to node js .
I am using requestify to fetch all the data from a webservice and once this is achieved i will 
call insert method to save all the entries.
Following is my code which i am using :-

```
 requestify.get('SERVER_URL_CODE_IGNITER_API')
       .then(function(response) {
  // This one works but gives me all the json element with a backward slash like 
  // containing escaping character . Which i dont want
  res.jsonp(response.body);  

  // When using following line i get an error 
  // Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  // syscall: 'getaddrinfo 
  // response.getBody();
 }
 );
```

My understanding is that response.getBody() should work and give the desired result without
escape characters but i am not able to get that working while response.body works but gives
me all the server data with backward slashes like this :-

"[{\"id\":\"212\",\"uid\":\"304\",\"fromLat\":\"28.5962491\",\"fromLon\":\"77.3396212\",\"toLat\":\"28.4594965\",\"toLon\":\"77.0266383\",\"fromName\":\"Sector 12, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India\",\"toName\":\"Gurgaon, Haryana, India\",\"startTime\":\"08:00 Hrs\",\"returnTime\":\"06:40 Hrs\",\"carModel\":\"suzuki baleno\",\"fuelType\":\"CNG\",\"chargePrice\":\"\",\"smoking\":\"Doesnt Matter\",\"name\":\"Ankur Gupta\",\"image\":\"http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/100000725036031\/picture?type=large\",\"email\":\"ankur1040@gmail.com\",\"fbid\":\"100000725036031\",\"age\":\"0\",\"sex\":\"0\",\"regid\":\"abc\",\"points\":\"0\",\"contact\":\"9711778805\"}]"

Comment: you are not sending response to the client when you are using response.getBody(); check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using response.getBody(); you are not sending response to the client. I guess you are trying to send the response to the client. You will need to do

```
res.jsonp(response.getBody());
```

response.body only gives you raw response body. you can do

```
console.log(response.body);
```

and

```
console.log(response.getBody());
```

to compare your output.

I am guessing you are using express framework?
your request handler should look like this

```
function(req, res){
  //other codes
  requestify.get('SERVER_URL_CODE_IGNITER_API')
    .then(function(response) {
       res.jsonp(response.getBody());
    });
}
```

Comment: I did this and then i got Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND',syscall: 'getaddrinfo

Comment: Are you sure you did called res.jsonp(response.getBody());? if yes can you edit it in your question.